# R terra::aggregate "Not compatible with requested type" error when using custom function

Tags: r, rcpp, terra

I am attempting to aggregate a spatraster based on the most common value in each subset (i.e., modal), except if the value corresponding to water is the most common it must make-up more than 75% of the grid cells or it will not be returned with the next most common value returned instead.

The current function takes the values of each group and returns a single numeric value corresponding to what the final aggregated cell value should be. The value of cells which must exceed 75% of the cells is indicated by the `drop` argument.

```
lc_aggr <- function(window, drop = 0, pct = 0.75) {
  x <- unique(window)
  if(length(x) == 1) {
    ret <- x
  } else {
    counts <- tabulate(match(window, x))
    pct_drop <- counts[match(drop, x)]/length(window)
    if(is.na(pct_drop) || pct_drop < pct) {
      counts <- counts[-match(drop, x)]
      ret <- x[which.max(counts)]
    } else {
      ret <- drop
    }
  }
}
```

This function seems to be working as expected. It returns a single numeric value for each group and it also works as expected with with all simple reprex I've tried. Frustratingly, it breaks when run with the actual dataset and returns `Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=double].` I'm not sure where to start with this error since it looks like the function is returning the expected values, what is required by `terra::aggregate`, and it seems to work with simple spatrasters. Although my limited familiarity with Rcpp certainly may contribute to my problems...

traceback:

```
9: stop(structure(list(message = "Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=double].", 
       call = NULL, cppstack = NULL), class = c("Rcpp::not_compatible", 
   "C++Error", "error", "condition")))
8: .External(structure(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid", 
       address = <pointer: 0x55bd9ec26070>, dll = structure(list(
           name = "Rcpp", path = "/home/mark/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so", 
           dynamicLookup = TRUE, handle = <pointer: 0x55bd9de508b0>, 
           info = <pointer: 0x55bd9d3559e0>), class = "DLLInfo"), 
       numParameters = -1L), class = c("ExternalRoutine", "NativeSymbolInfo"
   )), <pointer: 0x55bda2b30be0>, <pointer: 0x55bd9e6e78f0>, .pointer, 
       ...)
7: x@pnt$writeValues(v, start - 1, nrows)
6: .local(x, v, ...)
5: writeValues(out, v, outrows[i], outnr[i])
4: writeValues(out, v, outrows[i], outnr[i])
3: .local(x, ...)
2: terra::aggregate(evc, fact = 33, fun = lc_aggr)
1: terra::aggregate(evc, fact = 33, fun = lc_aggr)
```

Here is code to download the dataset to reproduce the error:
(I apologize that it requires downloading both a package and dataset)

```
devtools::install_github("bcknr/rlandfire")
library(rlandfire)
library(terra)

aoi <- c(-79.94116,  40.41411, -71.39884,  45.03770)
products <- "130EVC"
resolution <- 30
  
resp <- landfireAPI(products = products,
                    aoi = aoi, 
                    resolution = resolution)
  
dir.create(paste0(tempdir(),"/lf"))
utils::unzip(resp$path, exdir = paste0(tempdir(),"/lf"))
evc <- rast(paste0(tempdir(),"/lf/", resp$request$job_id,".tif"))
  
values(evc)[values(evc) != 11] <- 1
values(evc)[values(evc) == 11] <- 0
  
evc_aggr <- terra::aggregate(evc, fact = 33, fun = lc_aggr)
```

I've checked to make sure that that `lc_aggr` returns the expected values and class, tried reproducing the error on simple spatrasters and other similar datasets, projecting the dataset to lat/lon, modify arguments, changing the output class, etc. See above for a reproducible example.

Thanks for taking a look and any advice!

Edit: I should mention that using the named functions, for example `terra::aggregate(evc, fact = 33, fun = "modal")`, do work with the `evc` dataset without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your function does not work when `window` contains no  zeros

```
lc_aggr <- function(window, drop = 0, pct = 0.75) {
  x <- unique(window)
  if(length(x) == 1) {
    ret <- x
  } else {
    counts <- tabulate(match(window, x))
    pct_drop <- counts[match(drop, x)]/length(window)
    if(is.na(pct_drop) || pct_drop < pct) {
      counts <- counts[-match(drop, x)]
      ret <- x[which.max(counts)]
    } else {
      ret <- drop
    }
  }
  ret
}

s1 <- sample(0:5, 50, replace=TRUE)
s2 <- sample(1:5, 50, replace=TRUE)

lc_aggr(s1)
#[1] 2
lc_aggr(s2)
#integer(0)
```

Note, that I modified the last line of your function to get anything out of it at all with `s2`.